# compare two lists of files, ignoring file extension in one list

Tags: python

I have two lists

```
list1 = ['image1.png', 'image2.png', 'image3.png', 'image3.png']
list2 = ['image1.pdf', 'image2.eps', 'image3.ps']
```

I want to create a list which contains the names of list1, if the name (ignoring the extension) is contained in list2. For the example above the correct answer would be

```
['image1.png', 'image2.png', 'image3.png']
```

any idea how to do this?
thanks
carl

Comment: Try a list comprehension (http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)

Comment: I thought about something like new_list = [f for f in list1 and os.path.splitext(f)[0] in list2] but that gives an error...

Comment: you are awesome guys... instead of an and I had to use a if...

Comment: @carl I've posted an answer with **set** and list comprehensions. Take a look, you only need 1 line.

Comment: One liners are cool, but if this is going to be actual production code then readability wins. They're also easier to modify if additional requirements come along. The one-liner also does the split many more times than necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from os.path import splitext

list1 = ['image1.png', 'image2.png', 'image3.png', 'image3.png', 'image4.png', 'image3.jpg']
list2 = ['image1.pdf', 'image2.eps', 'image3.ps', 'image5.doc']

# Create a lookup set of the document names sans extensions.
documents = set([splitext(filename)[0] for filename in list2])

# Compare each stripped filename in list1 to the list of stripped document filenames.
matches = [filename for filename in set(list1) if splitext(filename)[0] in documents]

print matches
```

Output:

```
['image1.png', 'image2.png', 'image3.png', 'image3.jpg']
```

Note that it would have to be adapted for files with multiple extensions like `.tar.gz` if needed (`filename.partition(".")[0]` would do the trick). But that would mean that dots cannot be put anywhere in the filename because the *first* dot now delimits the extension.

Comment: This produces wrong output for the ops sample input. You have to `set(matches)` or it won't remove duplicates.

Comment: @SebastianWozny Ha, I wondered what you were on about. He changed that while I was answering it. Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `set` to get uniques and a list comprehension to do the comparison:

```
from os.path import splitext

list1 = ['image1.png', 'image2.png', 'image3.png', 'image3.png']
list2 = ['image1.pdf', 'image2.eps', 'image3.ps']
reference = set([splittext(item)[0] for item in list2]) #  Strip the extension
outcome = set([item for item in list1 if splittext(item)[0] in reference]) #  compare
print(outcome)
>>> 
{'image3.png', 'image2.png', 'image1.png'}
```

Comment: This will break if any of the filenames have extra periods in them: 'image1.test.png', for example.

Comment: Thanks! You might want to check your answer against what the OP asked.

Comment: I did... it never hurts to make your code more resilient for the next person to use this answer, however. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension with **`set`**:

```
list1 = ["image1.png", "image2.png", "image3.png", "image3.png"]
list2 = ["image1.pdf", "image2.eps", "image3.ps"]

print [x for x in set(list1) for y in set(list2) if x.split('.')[0] == y.split('.')[0]]
```

**Output:**

```
['image1.png', 'image2.png', 'image3.png']
```

Comment: This one-liner will split each name for each comparison, resulting in an exponential execution time.

Comment: @ScottA I don't know what are you talking about. Your code does it too. "Exponential execution time" hahaha, yeah right.

Comment: No... for the given input the one-liner will execute 18 split calls len(list1) * len(list2) * 2. My code will execute 6: len(list1) + len(list2). Your code is O(n^2), mine is O(n).

Comment: Yeah, **`exponential`** execution time.

Comment: Ah, heh, whoops. I meant it grows by the square, not exponentially. It's late on a Friday... but my code definitely does *not* do that. It's linear.

Answer (score 0):

```
def filename(name):
    return name.split('.')[0]

list2_filenames = [filename(name) for name in list2]
found_filenames = [name for name in list1 if filename(name) in list2_filenames]
```